# Get only URL from string - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a page with `Python` and `BeautifulSoup` library.

I have to get the URL only from this string. This actually is in `href` attribute of the `a` tag. I have scraped it but cannot seem to find a way to extract the URL from this

```
javascript:void%20window.open('/Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en','TC_POPUP','width=490,height=405,screenX=300,screenY=250,top=250,left=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no');
```

Comment: Would it be too easy to take a substring from ( to )?

Comment: Get sub string inside `()` and then explode it on the basis of `,` and then get first index value

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt notice there are more than 1 string inside the brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a regex, you could just partition it twice on something, (eg: `'`):

```
s.partition("'")[2].partition("'")[0]
# /Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en
```

Comment: Please see my answer too ... what would you suggest is the good one

Comment: @Mani by using partition, you only split "once", and you're guaranteed to get empty strings where the delimiter is not present. So 1) It's more efficient, and 2) it's safer, as your `.split` could raise an IndexError where it's not present... Your choice of delimiters is possibly more sensible though

Answer (score 2):

You can write a straightforward regex to extract the URL.

```
>>> import re
>>> href = "javascript:void%20window.open('/Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en','TC_POPUP','width=490,height=405,screenX=300,screenY=250,top=250,left=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no');"
>>> re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", href)
['/Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en', 'TC_POPUP', 'width=490,height=405,screenX=300,screenY=250,top=250,left=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no']
>>> _[0]
'/Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en'
```

The regex in question here is

```
'(.*?)'
```

Which reads "find a single-quote, followed by whatever (and capture the whatever), followed by another single quote, and do so non-greedily because of the `?` operator". This extracts the arguments of `window.open`; then, just pick the first one to get the URL.

You shouldn't have any nested `'` in your href, since those should be escaped to `%27`. If you do, though, this will not work, and you may need a solution that doesn't use regexes.

Comment: I will give it a try ... By the way .. It is also possible that I can first get the string in `()` and then explode it `,` and then get first element

Answer (score 1):

I did it that way.

```
terms = javascript:void%20window.open('/Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en','TC_POPUP','width=490,height=405,screenX=300,screenY=250,top=250,left=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no');

terms.split("('")[1].split("','")[0]
```

outputs

```
/Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick and ugly answer

```
href.split("'")[1]
```

Comment: Algorithm Rule #1 : why use 2 splits, when you can use 1

Comment: Your line produces an error ... thats why i said i could downvote you

Comment: `href = "javascript:void%20window.open('/Sheraton-Tucson-Hotel-177/tnc/150/24795/en','TC_POPUP','width=490,height=405,screenX=300,screenY=250,top=250,left=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no');"
print(href.split("'")[1])` This just runs fine. Dont know what you talking about